# Editing script on local machine

Tags: ssh

I always edit and execute code on my Raspberry Pi via SSH and Vim.

Can I open script on RPi in my Sublime Text on the local machine and after saving this script (CTRL + S), it'll save on RPi?

Answer (score 2):

I use a different editor/IDE and mount the RPi filesystem via nfs on my local system (e.g. path RPi:/ is exported via nfs on my RPi and locally mounted on /remote/rpi). Then I open the file e.g. /remote/rpi/home/pi/python/myPyProg.py and every save will save the file immediately on RPi.

Comment: Your answer is a good one. It would possibly be much better if you briefly explained how to do an NFS mount on your RPi from a PC/Mac/whatever.

Comment: I agree but frankly - there are so many questions how to export directories with nfs and very good answers on RaspberryPi. Why should I just copy and paste them here again? For example I searched for `nfs export` and got a lot of hits.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your main PC is running Windows, you could use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_ssh_client_for_windows) which supports synchronising your local directory on a PC with a remote directory (e.g. that of the Pi). See [their documentation on this feature](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date):

> Keep remote directory up to date is a unique feature of WinSCP. With it you may let WinSCP watch for changes in a local directory and have it automatically reflect the changes on the selected remote directory.
>
> Using it, you can, with some limitations, work with local files using your favorite tools and the effect would be as if you were working with remote files directly. In other words, the feature partially replaces commercial remote directory drive mapping tools.

When you update any file in the watched directory, WinSCP will synchronise it over SSH with the Pi's copy of the directory.

Comment: Just make sure to save files on the windows machine with "unix linebreaks".